# Draw arc from end of one arc with different center

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw an arc from A to dashed vertical line taking C2 as center.
First arc center is C1.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0:0){C1};
\node at (90:1){C2};

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (90:6);

\draw (90:2) arc (100:-130:2)node{A};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might got it wrong but I interpreted the question as a continous path so here it is; (you can separate them anyway)

We can use the `let` syntax, that allows you to save a node coordinate into a macro `\p<number>` and then access its components using `\x<number>` and `\y<number>`. This requires the `calc` library to be loaded.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0:0){C1};
\node (C2) at (90:1){C2};

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (90:6);

\draw (90:2) arc (90:-130:2)node(A){A} let \p1=($(A)-(C2)$),
                                         \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},
                                         \n2={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
      in arc (\n2:-270:\n1);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Change `100` into `90` (_First arc center is C1_) then use `\atan2(\y1,\x1)` to get the correct picture (with PGF/TikZ 3.0).

Comment: Last suggestion: you may use `-270` instead of `90` in last `arc` (question is not very clear...).

Comment: @PaulGaborit You are right it was both wrong and less beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `scope` with a shift of `y=1cm`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0:0){C1};
\node at (90:1)(c2){C2};

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (90:6);

\begin{scope}[yshift=1cm]
\draw[ultra thick] (90:2cm) arc (90:-130:2cm)node{A};
\end{scope}
%\draw[red] (c2.center) circle (2cm);    %% Uncomment to check the center

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the right answer.

I never seen the Tikz coordinate is defined as `(0:0)`, so I couldn't imagine what exactly its mean.

However, I draw a circle to get the right radius and as a prototype. Then I draw the arc from the end of the previous one (blue) and its inverse (red).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0:0){C1};
\node at (90:1){C2};

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (90:6);

\draw (90:2) arc (100:-130:2)node{A};

\end{tikzpicture}


% %
%   Draw circle to make sure we have the right radius
%
\vfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0:0){C1};
    \node(C2) at (90:1){C2};

    \draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (90:6);

    \draw (90:2) arc (100:-130:2)node(A){A};

    \draw[red] (C2) circle(2.7);

\end{tikzpicture}


% %
%   Draw arc from the end of the previous arc
%

\vfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0:0){C1};
    \node(C2) at (90:1){C2};

    \draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (90:6);

    \draw (90:2) arc (100:-130:2)node(A){A};

    \draw[blue] (A) arc (250:90:2.68);

\end{tikzpicture}


% %
%   Draw inverse of the new arc
%

\vfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0:0){C1};
    \node(C2) at (90:1){C2};

    \draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (90:6);

    \draw (90:2) arc (100:-130:2)node(A){A};

    \draw[blue] (A) arc (250:90:2.68);

    \draw[red] (A) arc (-110:90:2.68);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's the polar syntax `(angle:length)`. In fact anything with zero length would give the same point.

Comment: It is a good idea to draw a circle to find the radius...and then to use it to draw an arc.